# Shears using Matrix Methods

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Determine the equation of the image of the graph:
$$y=(x-1)^3 -2$$
after a shear of factor $1$ away from the $y$-axis, relative to the line $y=1$.

Comment: What are your own thoughts?

Comment: I know how to shear, but not relative to the line y=1

Comment: A shear relative to the line $y = 1$ means that any point on the line is kept constant. The shear $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ is relative to $y = 0$, since all points on the $x$-axis are kept constant. I'm a bit perplexed as to what you mean by "away from the $y$-axis" though.

Comment: "Parallel to the y-axis' might be a better way of explaining it

Comment: Compose a series of linear transformations:
1. Translate downwards one unit.
2. Perform the shear.
3. Translate upwards one unit.
You can do this by invoking a third dimension and performing a shear in this third dimension to emulate a 2-dimensional translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the graph $y=(x-1)^3-2$ with the variable $t$ like so:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
t\\
(t-1)^3-2
\end{array}\right)
$$
You can then transform this vector by translating it downwards one unit, performing the shear, then translating it back up. Because this involves doing a translation, we add an extra $1$ on the end of the previous vector so that it is $3$-dimensional, and perform a shear transformation in the three dimensions.

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array} \right ]
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&0&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1
\end{array} \right ]
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array} \right ]
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&0&0\\
0&1&-1\\
0&0&1
\end{array} \right ]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
t&\\
(t-1)^3-2\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{c}
(t-1)^3+t-3\\
(t-1)^3-2
\end{array}\right]$$
You now have a parametric equation for the resulting line in terms of a variable $t$ over the domain $\mathbb{R}$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
x(t)\\
y(t)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
(t-1)^3+t-3\\
(t-1)^3-2
\end{array}\right]$$

---

Note that in general the method above works, in this particular circumstance, you could probably skip doing the three linear transformations by observing that a shear of factor $1$ about $y=1$ is the same as doing a shear about $y=0$ and subtracting $1$ from $x$ afterwards.
Thus:

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array} \right ]
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&1&-1\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array} \right ]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
t&\\
(t-1)^3-2\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Gives you the same result. Since we're only dealing with one transformation now and we're ignoring the third component of the solution anyway, we can just do:
$$
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&1&-1\\
0&1&0
\end{array} \right ]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
t&\\
(t-1)^3-2\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$

Suppose we have some arbitrary function $y(x)$ sheared by a factor $k$ about the line $y=c$. Then we would do:
$$
\left [ \begin{array}{a}
1&k&-kc\\
0&1&0
\end{array} \right ]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
t\\
y(t)\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
We'd then have a parametric equation for the resulting $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ graph in terms of $t$.

---

In short, if you want to compose a translation with your linear transformations, invoke an extra dimension and use that. In this case, you may be able to tell immediately that this final matrix is the only transformation necessary. Pretend you're doing a normal shear, but compensate for the fact that it's actually off-axis by subtracting the appropriate amount from $x$.

Comment: Could you possibly generalise it to allow it to be relative to any line of the form y=c ?

Comment: If you want it to work for $y=c$, then you can adjust the translation amount to $c$ instead of $1$. Don't worry too much about the first part of the response-- it's there to try and build your understanding of it. In practice, you would probably short-cut it with the way that I've demonstrated last.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a generalisation for a shear of $k$ about $y=c$.

Comment: @Jim I've realized that this answer is not correct! I'm very sorry about this; you should unmark this answer as accepted. The penultimate step in my working is correct, but you can't simply divide through and multiply by $x$ the way I did-- you run into issues with the domain of $t$ and $x$. You can express the line parametrically in terms of $t$ though as it is before dividing through by the first component of the vector. I'll edit the answer appropriately.

Comment: Okay, everything's good now. The graph can be expressed parametrically.